# Comment on posts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hey Guys I'm trying to store comments for every service in my website

first I created the relationships between user,comment,service
then when I try to add a comment I get an error :

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'services_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `user_id`, `services_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ggg, 1, , 2018-03-20 21:12:17, 2018-03-20 21:12:17))**

That's the service model : Service.php

```
                 <?php
      namespace App; 
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Service extends Model
      {

public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\comment');

}}
```

That's the model Comment.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Comment extends Model
       {

public function  user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}


public function  services() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}}
```

That's the model User.php

```
               <?php

             namespace App;

             use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
             use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

            class User extends Authenticatable
            {  
               use Notifiable;

        protected $fillable = ['username', 'email','password','tel','ville','description','image','diplomes','langues',  
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function services(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}

public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}}
```

the route:

```
 Route::post('/services/{services_id}','CommentsController@store');
```

Store method in CommentsController :

```
 public function store(Request $request, $services_id)
{
   $this->validate($request,array(
        'body'=>'required',
    )); 
  $comment=new Comment;
  $service=Service::find($services_id);
  $comment->body=$request->body;
  $comment->user_id=$request->user()->id;
  $comment->services()->associate($service);
  $comment->save();
  $request->session()->flash('notif','success');
  return back(); }
```

And that's the blade page

```
<form class="col s12"  method="post" action="/services/{$services->id}">
{{ csrf_field() }}


                     <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">insert_comment</i>
      <textarea id="textarea1" name="body" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
      <label for="textarea1" style="color: black;">Commentaire</label>
    </div>
  </div>     

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col s12 center-align">

                <input type="submit" value="confirmer" class="btn-large purple  hoverable">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: you are providing a null value : `ggg, 1, , ` so `$comment->services()->associate($service);` must resolve to null

Comment: yes I know it's coming from it but I didn't know how to correct that.

Comment: We need to see the code that creates de View. You are probably not sending the `$services`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'services_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into comments (body, user_id, **services_id**, updated_at, created_at) values (ggg, 1, **MISSING VALUE** , 2018-03-20 21:12:17, 2018-03-20 21:12:17))

Your query want to put to database `services_id` but it is undefined in yoour `request`

So debug it:

Make `dd($request)` and see the **services_id** value

Guess CommentController should look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, $services_id)
{
   $this->validate($request,array(
        'body'=>'required',
    )); 
  $comment=new Comment;
  $service=Service::find($services_id);
  $comment->body=$request->body;
  $comment->user_id=$request->user()->id;
  $comment->service_id=$services_id; //here I made change!!!
  $comment->save();
  $request->session()->flash('notif','success');
  return back(); }
```

Comment: Make dd($request) and see the services_id value

Comment: Look now at my answer - change in commentController

Comment: a new error shows up !



SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '{$services->id}' for column 'services_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `comments` (`body`, `user_id`, `services_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (fff, 1, {$services->id}, 2018-03-20 21:38:34, 2018-03-20 21:38:34))

Comment: Looks like you're doing `$comment->service_id='{$services->id}';` for some reason. Variable expansion doesn't work within single quotes (only in double quotes), and is completely unnecessary here. Remove the quotes and curly braces: `$comment->service_id=$services->id;`

Comment: it worked finally thank you much guys!
the issue was coming from the braces! thank you so much